# Ocultar modal segun respuesta json ajax jquery laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax, bootstrap, modal

estoy haciendo trabajando en un pequeño codigo que lo que hace es cargar archivos, guardar la ruta en la base de datos y mover dichos archivos a una carpeta en el storage de laravel, me va funcionando bien solo que estoy trancado en una parte especial: cuando se esta haciendo el insert a la base de datos en el frontend muestro una ventana modal con una barra de progreso, este modal deberia ocultarse y mostrar un mensaje en la vista cuando termino de hacer el insert, cosa que hace a medias, muestra el mensaje de exito pero no oculta el modal jeje, he revisado varias veces pero no encuentro que puede estar mal, tengo el controlador con este codigo:
public function guardarCargaArchivos (Request $request){

```
    $idVehiculo = $request->get('vehiculo_id');

    if($request->hasFile('imagen')){
        foreach ($request->file('imagen') as $key => $value) {
            $image_name = $value->getClientOriginalName();


            $value->move('storage/docs_vehiculo2', $image_name);
            $projectImages = new DocumentoAuto();
            $projectImages->imageable_id = $idVehiculo;
            $projectImages->ruta = 'docs_vehiculo1/'.$image_name;
            $projectImages->imageable_type = $idVehiculo;
            $projectImages->comentario = $request->get('comentario')[$key];
            $projectImages->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
            $projectImages->save();
        }
        return response()->json(['respuesta'=>'ok']);
   }
```

y en la vista, el codigo ajax/jquery lo tengo asi:
//SUBMIT FORM IMAGENES

```
$('#formImagenes').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    let TotalFiles = $('#imagen')[0].files.length; //Total files
    let files = $('#imagen')[0];

    $('#modalEspera').modal('show');

    for (let i = 0; i < TotalFiles; i++) {
        formData.append('files' + i, files.files[i]);
    }
    formData.append('TotalFiles', TotalFiles);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "{{ url('sistema/vehiculo/doc/cargar')}}",
        data: formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function (data) {
            //$('#modalEspera').modal('hide');
            console.log(data);
            if(data.respuesta = 'ok'){
                $('#modalEspera').modal('hide');
                $('.exitoImagen').show();
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            $('#modalEspera').modal('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

y el modal en la vista:

```
<!-- Modal Espera-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalEspera" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Subiendo Documento(s), por favor espere...</h5>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Alguien ve en que puedo estar fallando?

Saludos cordiales